# How to save Data if Input type file is dynamic in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have `Employee` form in which I need to save employee document, the condition is this document is dynamic which coming from `Master_DocumentType` and it's not fixed. I need to save all employee data and its document so far I have created a form to create and have a button which will open a modal popup where all document input field is bound.

I need a way where I can save `Employee` data with its document details.

I am saving data on post request and modal popup is another window I need a way to transfer all input of type file's data to main window create by using jQuery or any good approach is there.

Please suggest some good approach.

Employee class

```
public class EmployeeVM : BaseViewModel<EmployeeDto>
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Employee Code")]
    public string EmpCode { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [DisplayName("Employee First Name")]
    public string EmpFName { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [DisplayName("Employee Middle Name")]
    public string EmpMName { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [DisplayName("Employee Last Name")]
    public string EmpLName { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Select Designation")]
    public int EmpDesignationID { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Employee Email")]
    public string EmpEmail { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [DisplayName("Employee DOB")]
    public string EmpDOB { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [DisplayName("Employee Joining Date")]
    public string EmpJoiningDate { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [DisplayName("Employee Exit Date")]
    public string EmpExitDate { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [DisplayName("Employee Contact")]
    public string EmpContact { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [DisplayName("Employee PAN Number")]
    public string EmpPAN { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [DisplayName("Employee Aadhar Number")]
    public string EmpAadhar { get; set; }= string.Empty;
    [DisplayName("Employee Can Login")]
    public bool EmpCanLogin { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<DesignationDto> DesignationDropdownList { get; set; } = new List<DesignationDto>();

    public DesignationDto Designation { get; set; } = new DesignationDto();
}
```

MasterDocumentType

```
public class MasterDocumentType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string DocName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Remark { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public bool IsRequired { get; set; }
}
```

Create form

```
@model EmployeeVM
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Employee : Create";
}
@section Styles{
    <link href="~/css/classic.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/css/classic.date.css" rel="stylesheet" />
}
<h4>Employee : Create</h4>
<nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
    <ol class="breadcrumb">
        <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a></li>
        <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a asp-controller="Employee" asp-action="Index">Employee</a></li>
        <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Create</li>
    </ol>
</nav>
<hr />
<div class="form-control" style="padding:10px">
    <form class="row g-3" method="post" asp-action="Create">

        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="form-check form-switch">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" role="switch" asp-for="EmpCanLogin">
                <label class="form-check-label" asp-for="EmpCanLogin">Generate Login For This User</label>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
            <label asp-for="EmpFName" class="form-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="EmpFName" class="form-control" placeholder="Employee First Name">
            <span asp-validation-for="EmpFName" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <label asp-for="EmpMName" class="form-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="EmpMName" class="form-control" placeholder="Employee Middle Name">
            <span asp-validation-for="EmpMName" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            <label asp-for="EmpLName" class="form-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="EmpLName" class="form-control" placeholder="Employee Last Name">
            <span asp-validation-for="EmpLName" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="col-4">
            @{
                var designationList = new SelectList(Model.DesignationDropdownList, "DesignationId", "DesignationName");
            }
            <label class="form-label" asp-for="EmpDesignationID">Select Designation</label>
            <select asp-for="EmpDesignationID" class="form-select" asp-items="@designationList">
                <option selected>Select Designation</option>
            </select>
            <span asp-validation-for="EmpDesignationID" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <label asp-for="EmpEmail" class="form-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="EmpEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Employee Email">
            <span asp-validation-for="EmpEmail" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
            <label asp-for="EmpDOB" class="form-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="EmpDOB" class="form-control" placeholder="Pick a Employee DOB">
            <span asp-validation-for="EmpDOB" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <label asp-for="EmpJoiningDate" class="form-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="EmpJoiningDate" class="form-control" placeholder="Pick a Joining Date">
            <span asp-validation-for="EmpJoiningDate" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            <label asp-for="EmpExitDate" class="form-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="EmpExitDate" class="form-control" placeholder="Pick a Exit Date">
            <span asp-validation-for="EmpExitDate" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
            <label asp-for="EmpContact" class="form-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="EmpContact" class="form-control" placeholder="Employee Contact">
            <span asp-validation-for="EmpContact" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            <label asp-for="EmpPAN" class="form-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="EmpPAN" class="form-control" placeholder="Employee PAN">
            <span asp-validation-for="EmpPAN" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            <label asp-for="EmpAadhar" class="form-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="EmpAadhar" class="form-control" placeholder="Employee Aadhar">
            <span asp-validation-for="EmpAadhar" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-12">
            <span class="btn btn-primary" id="btnUploadDoc">Upload Documents</span>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    <script src="~/js/picker.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/picker.date.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#EmpDOB').pickadate();
            $('#EmpJoiningDate').pickadate();
            $('#EmpExitDate').pickadate();

            $('#btnUploadDoc').on('click',function(){

                $.post('/getDocumentView').done(result => {

                    mdlA.id = "getDocumentView";
                    mdlA.title = `Upload Employee Documents`;
                    mdlA.content = result;
                    mdlA.show(mdlA.size.large);
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Document upload modal popup

```
@model IEnumerable<MasterDocumentTypeDto>
@{
    int rowId = 0;
}

<form asp-action="UpdateGuestCategory" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Sr. No.</th>
                <th scope="col">Room Type</th>
                <th scope="col" class="text-center">Select File</th>
                <th scope="col" class="text-center">File</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="table-group-divider">
            @if (Model != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <input type="hidden" asp-for="@item.Id" />
                        <th scope="row">@(rowId + 1)</th>
                        <td>@item.DocName</td>
                        <td class="text-center">
                            <div class="form-input">
                                <input type="file" class="form-control" placeholder="Employee Email">
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    rowId = rowId + 1;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row" colspan="5" class="text-center">No Records Found!</th>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5 ms-4">
            
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 text-end">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: In my opinion, you can try some plugins to upload file with modal, Please refer to this [link](https://medium.com/scrum-and-coke/integrate-asp-net-file-upload-with-bootstrap-modal-and-toastr-9d115efd6731).

Comment: Thank for reply @XinranShen, I am collecting the data by using class modal but I need the employee docs additionally by using modal popup and submit the data with documents, As modal popup is partial view not the part of main page.

Comment: By the way for now I have solve the issue by converting image into Base64 and then append using input type hidden with class fields name.